# Modify a previously written line in console C Codeblocks

Tags: c, console, codeblocks

I am doing a little test app and i was wondering if there any way to delete a previously printed line in the console.What i actually hope of achieving is showing the user a countdown in the right hand corner of the console.I am working in C, not C++, and using Codeblocks, not that it would be relevant.

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest looking for a curses (or ncurses) library for your platform. Note also -- your question has nothing at all to do with codeblocks -- that's an IDE, not a method of printing / changing print / running algorithms / anything else you can do in code.

Answer (score 0):

When you write to the console, what you're really doing is writing to file handles corresponding to stdout and stderr. If you were writing to a file that wasn't presented to a user in real time, it wouldn't be a big deal to 'back up' after writing something, and overwrite some section of the file with new data. However, since characters written to stdout / stderr are immediately presented to the user, there isn't a simple way to 'back up' and write new data to the console.

One feasible solution is to figure out the size of the console, and print out enough whitespace to fill up the console each time you want to update a value. For example, if you know that the user's console is 20 rows tall, and you want to display some updating value in the upper left corner of the console, you could print out 20 newlines followed by whatever data you want to output. However, this also means that any other data you're displaying in the console is going to have to be printed out again, too. This might end up being slower and uglier than intended.

I suggest trying out a curses library, as mah suggested. [Here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) is a nice overview of how to get started with ncurses.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i, c = 80;
    char *cp = getenv("COLUMNS");
    if (cp) c = atoi(cp);
    for (i = 10; printf("%*d\r", c-1, i), fflush(stdout), i; --i) sleep(1);
    printf("\n");
}
```